# Get the RGB-hexadecimal values from an array and give it to an malloc-array as int

Tags: c, arrays, hex, rgb, atoi

I need a method, how I can get a hexadecimal number from an array, then give it to a variable with the type int. I know that sounds easy but I need it in a "special way" - for example:

I have given a RGB hex color: 01a7ff - and I saved the value of R, G and B in extra arrays - looking like this:

```
char red[3];
red[0] = '0';
red[1] = '1';
red[2] = '\0';

char green[3];
green[0] = 'a';
green[1] = '7';
green[2] = '\0';

char blue[3];
blue[0] = 'f';
blue[1] = 'f';
blue[2] = '\0';
```

Now I want to give the complete array of red, green and blue to a malloc reserved array so it looks like this:

```
char *data;
data = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);

data[0] = 01; //red array
data[1] = a7; //green array
data[2] = ff; //blue array
```

I first tried using atoi() but that didn't work if the array had also de hexadecimal literals (a,b,c,d,e,f) - has anyone a solution for me?

Cheers

Comment: `man strtoul` will help.

Comment: i tried using `strtol` but all the time i did that the hexadecimal was then converted into a decimal number.. is `man strtoul` different?

Comment: then what do you want? Put them in char array?

Comment: Looks like a basic misunderstanding of data representation.

Comment: I want the hexadecimal numbers, which are stored in an array (for ex
green a7) to be copied as a7 to data[1] - so literally I want: `data[1] = green;`

Comment: You wan't `data` to be an array of pointers to strings? Or even an array of strings?

Comment: Ok I see that probably doesn't work.. I think I missunderstood something..

Comment: `char *data` may not work as expected; plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`, and `0xff` may not fit into a `signed char`. Consider instead `unsigned char *data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that data holds unsigned char values this should do:

```
data[0] = (unsigned char) strtol(red, NULL, 16);
data[1] = (unsigned char) strtol(green, NULL, 16);
data[2] = (unsigned char) strtol(blue, NULL, 16);
```

Note: It is enough to use unsigned char to hold data value from 0 to 255

Comment: thank you! That was exactly what I wanted - now I understand. :)

Comment: Note that OP `char *data` may lead to unexpected results for both `data[1] = strtol(green, NULL, 16);`  and `data[2] = strtol(blue, NULL, 16);`

Comment: @DavidBowling You are right! I added the clarification for the data type.

Comment: This is true, the regular `char` data type as I understand it accepts values -127 to 127.